# ADFS 4.0 OpenID connect customizing access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs, openid-connect

I have an ADFS 4.0 OpenId Connect setup with Application Group "Web browser accessing a web application". I'm using implicit flow and able to successfully login from my web app receiving id_token and access_token.

Next I'm ussing the access token in requests send from the wep app to API server. What I want to do is customize the access token format - add additional params because by default I only have:
aud, iss, iat, exp, apptype, appid, authmethod, urn, auth_time, ver, scp.
I need the 'sub' param to put the logged username in the access token and some additional params for my api server/resource server to perform custom security logic before giving access to a resource.

How can I customize the access token in this flow in the ADFS 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to do it by editing web application properties (open Application Groups, double click application group, double click on Web application)

Tab 'Issuance Transform Rules'. Added rules to pass claims from AD like group or name and those claims now appear in the access token.